# Понимаю, что хотят, но не знаю как исправить. error CS0019: Operator

Tags: c#, unity3d

Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(39,50): error CS0019: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'[image: Ошибку выбивает на последней строчке]

Comment: Вряд ли вы действительно понимаете, что не так, иначе понимали бы, что не понимаете что делаете... В общем viewCam.localRotation.eulerAngles - это Vector3. И вы умножаете его на Vector3. Но оператор умножения * не определен для Vector3, другими словами вы не можете перемножить два вектора. Вам вряд ли кто-то поможет, потому что непонятно что вы хотите получить. Вам следует разобраться в этим.  И да, выкладывайте код текстом!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Спасибо, что подали палец. Буду пробовать

Comment: Попробуйте вставить код текстом, пока этот вопрос не побил все рекорды по минусам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы перемножить два `Vector3` Используют **[Vector3.Scale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html)**, а не обычный знак умножения

Comment: Весь прикол в том, что на обучающем видео все работает.

Comment: Пусть на обучающем видео и скажут, почему это у других не работает))

Comment: @SNRDELL А зачем вам произведение векторов по компонентам?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgjth3nRsFc&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Uzpqn_76LTJYa9cn3DzUk6  Видео 22.02 мин.